# Pythontex Problem

Tags: texstudio, python, pythontex

I dont know how I cant solve the problem with pythonTeX, I've install Anaconda(python) and I thought that the packages were the problem but no, the problem is with LaTeX, TeXstudio is my tex-editor and Im pretty sure that the python code is okay because I'm compiling the example(pythontex_gallery.tex) of the pythonTeX package  [pythontex_0.12.zip](https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex/tree/master/package_downloads), It doesn't work for me, nor Linux neither in W7, I hope that somebody can help me, thank u so much!

[image: This is the problem]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It would be very helpful if you posted an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) that generates the problem behavior you are looking to fix. It would also be helpful if you indicated your workflow; e.g., "first run LaTeX, then run python, then re-run LaTeX."

Comment: Just a guess, and perhaps more applicable to the windows system than the Linux: can they find each other?  You might also want to check that pythontex can find the *right* TeX install; some python disibutions (those which include matplotlib) bring a small TeX distribution with them (for things like axis labels) and pythontex may be looking for that.

Comment: Are you running LaTeX, then `pythontex.py` (or `pythontex.exe`, or `pythontex.bat`, depending on system), and then LaTeX again? This looks like what happens when the `pythontex` script that processes code hasn't been run.

Comment: Yes, I've running pythontex.bat in W7 but it doesn't work, so I dont know how to do that in linux with the path, I installed python (spyder, iphython) from synaptic package manager, @ChrisH I've looking the packages installed that pythontex could use, in Anaconda python (pygments, matplotlib, numPy, sciPy) and in LaTeX pythontex package fancyvrb and other that I dont remember

Comment: @Mico The log issue in texstudio mentioned some comments with  "Non-existent" so I dont know how to solve it

Comment: With both TeX and python I've had worse path issues on Windows than Linux. But I've never used them together (except in the very limited sense within matplotlib).